# How to unscale rolled scaled data

Tags: r, data.table, time-series

I am working with time-series data and the model seems to improve around 10% when the scale data follows a rolling window. To calculate the rolling scale, I coded the folling function:

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.table(index = 1:100, x = rnorm(100))

roll_scale <- function(x, n = 3, ...) {

     xout <- frollapply(x, n , FUN = function(z) c( scale(z)[n, 1]), ... )
     return(xout) 
    }
d[, sData := roll_scale(x)]
```

Based on the comment [how can I use rollapply with scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247235/how-can-i-use-rollapply-with-scale])

After modelling the data, I would like to predict the most recent timepoints and bring the outcome to the original scale. However, this seems trickier than I expected. Here is my attempt through DMwR::unscale:

```
roll_UNscale <- function(scaled, Ref_values, n = 3, ...) {

  xout <- frollapply(scaled, n , FUN = function(z, Ref_values) {
    c(DMwR::unscale(scaled, scale(Ref_values))[ n,])

    }, ..., Ref_values =  Ref_values)

  return(xout) 
}

d[, roll_UNscale(sData, x)]
```

I hope you can give me a hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of thinking, I have come up with the solution. In a nutshell, what I need to roll is only the reference vector. Here it is:

```
roll_UNscale <- function(scaled, Ref_values, n = 3, align = "right", ...) {

  means <- frollmean(Ref_values, n = n) 
  stds <- frollapply(x = Ref_values, n = n, FUN = sd)
  unscaled <- scaled * stds + means
  return(unscaled) 
}
```

I hope this can help someone.